# Течет память?

Tags: утечка-памяти, node.js

Снимок графика:

[image]

Зеленый график - heapUsed.

Черный - heapTotal.

Синий - RSS.

HeadUsed имеет форму пилы: растет и падает, т.е. память очищается.
HeapTotal и RSS растет постоянно.

Если прекратить все коннекты, то heapUsed упадет до 92мб, а HeapTotal и RSS так и 
останутся по ~1гб.

График:

[image]

Почему? Признак утечки?

Спасибо.

Comment: Течет, а что за код? Повторяется ли, если сделать простейший http сервер? (можно, например, клонировать большой кусок данных для теста)

Answer (score 1):

Если heapUsed не растёт, то, скорее всего, утечки нет.

Answer (score 0):

Есть интересный пост [Как исправить ошибку в Node.js ...](http://habrahabr.ru/post/264851/)

Вообще утечки для ноды не новость, но надо смотреть на код.

Возможно у вас где-то не закрываются дескрипторы, сокеты и т.п.